# GenemuFormBundle not translating "The captcha is not valid" To locale language (fr)?

Tags: symfony, bundle

All in the title, and in the validators.fr.yml all is good, this is it:

```
The captcha is invalid.: Le captcha est invalide.
genemu_form:
  recaptcha:
    incorrect-captcha-sol: Le captcha n'est pas valide.
    invalid-site-private-key: La clé privée est invalide.
```

Comment: Is the indentation shown in your question the same as in your real file... or did you make a copy/paste mistake here? Please fix that or report back that this is really how your file looks. Where exactly did you put that file (which folder)?

Comment: no the identification is not the same but I've correct it now in the question. because I made copy/paste. First it was in Bundle/FormBundle/Resources/translation but since the translation is not working I copied translation folder to app/Resources.